# Removing all empty elements from a hash / YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, yaml

How would I go about removing all empty elements (empty list items) from a nested Hash or YAML file?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could add a compact method to Hash like this

```
class Hash
  def compact
    delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
  end
end
```

or for a version that supports recursion

```
class Hash
  def compact(opts={})
    inject({}) do |new_hash, (k,v)|
      if !v.nil?
        new_hash[k] = opts[:recurse] && v.class == Hash ? v.compact(opts) : v
      end
      new_hash
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: compact should only remove nils. Not falsy values

Comment: This has a problem: `Hash#delete_if` is a destructive operation, while `compact` methods don't modify the object. You can use `Hash#reject`. Or call the method `Hash#compact!`.

Comment: Please note that `compact` and `compact!` come standard in Ruby => 2.4.0, and Rails => 4.1. They are non-recursive though.

Comment: The recursive version does not work with `HashWithIndifferentAccess`..

Check my version at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958201/1519240

Comment: Check out mine recursive implementation based on standard `compact` and `transform_values` below!

Answer (score 182):

Rails 4.1 added [Hash#compact](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact) and [Hash#compact!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact-21) as a core extensions to Ruby's `Hash` class. You can use them like this:

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
hash.compact                        
# => { a: true, b: false }
hash                                
# => { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
hash.compact!                        
# => { a: true, b: false }
hash                                
# => { a: true, b: false }
{ c: nil }.compact                  
# => {}
```

Heads up: this implementation is not recursive. As a curiosity, they implemented it using `#select` instead of `#delete_if` for performance reasons. See [here for the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tinogomes/8332883).

In case you want to backport it to your Rails 3 app:

```
# config/initializers/rails4_backports.rb

class Hash
  # as implemented in Rails 4
  # File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/compact.rb, line 8
  def compact
    self.select { |_, value| !value.nil? }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice and tidy, but probably worth noting that unlike the accepted answer the Rails extension isn't recursive?

Comment: It omits empty hashes.

Answer (score 148):

Use [hsh.delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if). In your specific case, something like: `hsh.delete_if { |k, v| v.empty? }`

Comment: Recursive one: `proc = Proc.new { |k, v| v.kind_of?(Hash) ? (v.delete_if(&l); nil) : v.empty? }; hsh.delete_if(&proc)`

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your otherwise correct answer: proc = Proc.new { |k, v| v.kind_of?(Hash) ? (v.delete_if(&proc); nil) : v.empty? }; hsh.delete_if(&proc)

Comment: It would be great if #compact was added to Hash.

Comment: @BSeven it seems they heard you! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact (Rails 4.1)

Comment: This will throw a `NoMethodError` if `v` is nil.

Comment: You can use .delete_if { |k, v| v.blank? }

Answer (score 50):

### compact_blank (Rails 6.1+)

If you are using `Rails` (or a standalone `ActiveSupport`), starting from version `6.1`, there is a [`compact_blank`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) method which removes `blank` values from hashes.

It uses [`Object#blank?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) under the hood for determining if an item is blank.

```rb
{ a: "", b: 1, c: nil, d: [], e: false, f: true }.compact_blank
# => { b: 1, f: true }
```

Here is a [link to the docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) and a [link to the relative PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36412).

A destructive variant is also available. See [`Hash#compact_blank!`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact_blank-21).

---

If you need to remove only `nil` values,

please, consider using Ruby build-in [`Hash#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Hash.html#method-i-compact) and [`Hash#compact!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Hash.html#method-i-compact-21) methods.

```rb
{ a: 1, b: false, c: nil }.compact
# => { a: 1, b: false }
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Ruby 2.4+, you can call `compact` and `compact!`

```
h = { a: 1, b: false, c: nil }
h.compact! #=> { a: 1, b: false }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact-21

Comment: I also find useful is the [Hash.except(:key) method](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)

Answer (score 7):

This one would delete empty hashes too:

```
swoop = Proc.new { |k, v| v.delete_if(&swoop) if v.kind_of?(Hash);  v.empty? }
hsh.delete_if &swoop
```

Comment: rails version, that also works with values of other types than Array, Hash, or String (like Fixnum): `swoop = Proc.new { |k, v| v.delete_if(&swoop) if v.kind_of?(Hash);  v.blank? }`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) to remove empty key/value pairs from a ruby Hash.

```
# Remove empty strings
{ a: 'first', b: '', c: 'third' }.reject { |key,value| value.empty? } 
#=> {:a=>"first", :c=>"third"}

# Remove nil
{a: 'first', b: nil, c: 'third'}.reject { |k,v| v.nil? } 
# => {:a=>"first", :c=>"third"}

# Remove nil & empty strings
{a: '', b: nil, c: 'third'}.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v.empty? } 
# => {:c=>"third"}
```

Comment: FYI: `.empty?` throws error for numbers, so you can use `.blank?` in `Rails`

Answer (score 5):

works for both hashes and arrays

```
module Helpers
  module RecursiveCompact
    extend self

    def recursive_compact(hash_or_array)
      p = proc do |*args|
        v = args.last
        v.delete_if(&p) if v.respond_to? :delete_if
        v.nil? || v.respond_to?(:"empty?") && v.empty?
      end

      hash_or_array.delete_if(&p)
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. based on someones answer, cant find

usage - `Helpers::RecursiveCompact.recursive_compact(something)`

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is a bit old but I came up with a better solution which supports Multidimensional hashes. It uses delete_if? except its multidimensional and cleans out anything with a an empty value by default and if a block is passed it is passed down through it's children.

```
# Hash cleaner
class Hash
    def clean!
        self.delete_if do |key, val|
            if block_given?
                yield(key,val)
            else
                # Prepeare the tests
                test1 = val.nil?
                test2 = val === 0
                test3 = val === false
                test4 = val.empty? if val.respond_to?('empty?')
                test5 = val.strip.empty? if val.is_a?(String) && val.respond_to?('empty?')

                # Were any of the tests true
                test1 || test2 || test3 || test4 || test5
            end
        end

        self.each do |key, val|
            if self[key].is_a?(Hash) && self[key].respond_to?('clean!')
                if block_given?
                    self[key] = self[key].clean!(&Proc.new)
                else
                    self[key] = self[key].clean!
                end
            end
        end

        return self
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a deep_compact method for this that recursively filters out nil records (and optionally, blank records as well):

```
class Hash
  # Recursively filters out nil (or blank - e.g. "" if exclude_blank: true is passed as an option) records from a Hash
  def deep_compact(options = {})
    inject({}) do |new_hash, (k,v)|
      result = options[:exclude_blank] ? v.blank? : v.nil?
      if !result
        new_value = v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.deep_compact(options).presence : v
        new_hash[k] = new_value if new_value
      end
      new_hash
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's `Hash#compact`, `Hash#compact!` and `Hash#delete_if!` do not work on nested `nil`, `empty?` and/or `blank?` values. Note that the latter two methods are destructive, and that all `nil`, `""`, `false`, `[]` and `{}` values are counted as `blank?`.

`Hash#compact` and `Hash#compact!` are only available in Rails, or Ruby version 2.4.0 and above.

Here's a non-destructive solution that removes all empty arrays, hashes, strings and `nil` values, while keeping all `false` values:

(`blank?` can be replaced with `nil?` or `empty?` as needed.)

```
def remove_blank_values(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), new_hash|
    unless v.blank? && v != false
      v.is_a?(Hash) ? new_hash[k] = remove_blank_values(v) : new_hash[k] = v
    end
  end
end
```

A destructive version:

```
def remove_blank_values!(hash)
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.blank? && v != false
      hash.delete(k)
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
      hash[k] = remove_blank_values!(v)
    end
  end
end
```

Or, if you want to add both versions as instance methods on the `Hash` class:

```
class Hash
  def remove_blank_values
    self.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), new_hash|
      unless v.blank? && v != false
        v.is_a?(Hash) ? new_hash[k] = v.remove_blank_values : new_hash[k] = v
      end
    end
  end

  def remove_blank_values!
    self.each_pair do |k, v|
      if v.blank? && v != false
        self.delete(k)
      elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
        v.remove_blank_values!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Other options:

- Replace `v.blank? && v != false` with `v.nil? || v == ""` to strictly remove empty strings and `nil` values
- Replace `v.blank? && v != false` with `v.nil?` to strictly remove `nil` values
- Etc.

EDITED 2017/03/15 to keep `false` values and present other options

Answer (score 3):

our version: 
it also cleans the empty strings and nil values

```
class Hash

  def compact
    delete_if{|k, v|

      (v.is_a?(Hash) and v.respond_to?('empty?') and v.compact.empty?) or
          (v.nil?)  or
          (v.is_a?(String) and v.empty?)
    }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

In Simple one liner for deleting null values in Hash,

```
rec_hash.each {|key,value| rec_hash.delete(key) if value.blank? }
```

Comment: careful, `blank?` goes for empty strings as well

Answer (score 3):

Could be done with [facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) library (a missing features from standard library), like that:

```
require 'hash/compact'
require 'enumerable/recursively'
hash.recursively { |v| v.compact! }
```

Works with any Enumerable (including Array, Hash).

Look how [recursively method](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/e79ab3c17dce8a85cdc23c231f573758636f5adb/lib/core/facets/enumerable/recursively.rb#L7) is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773555/1519240 works, but not with `HashWithIndifferentAccess` or other classes that are kind of Hash..

Here is the version I am using:

```
def recursive_compact
  inject({}) do |new_hash, (k,v)|
    if !v.nil?
      new_hash[k] = v.kind_of?(Hash) ? v.recursive_compact : v
    end
    new_hash
  end
end
```

`kind_of?(Hash)` will accept more classes that are like a Hash.

You can also replace `inject({})` by `inject(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new)` if you want to access the new hash using both symbol and string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be best to use a self recursive method.  That way it goes as deep as is needed.  This will delete the key value pair if the value is nil or an empty Hash.

```
class Hash
  def compact
    delete_if {|k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.compact.empty? : v.nil? }
  end
end
```

Then using it will look like this:

```
x = {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>3}, :d=>nil, :e=>{:f=>nil}, :g=>{}}
# => {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>3}, :d=>nil, :e=>{:f=>nil}, :g=>{}} 
x.compact
# => {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>3}}
```

To keep empty hashes you can simplify this to.

```
class Hash
  def compact
    delete_if {|k,v| v.compact if v.is_a?(Hash); v.nil? }
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm. circular references could lead to infinite loop IIUC.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hash   
  def compact
    def _empty?(val)
      case val
      when Hash     then val.compact.empty?
      when Array    then val.all? { |v| _empty?(v) }
      when String   then val.empty?
      when NilClass then true
      # ... custom checking 
      end
    end

    delete_if { |_key, val| _empty?(val) }   
  end 
end
```

Comment: Note that "when Hash   then compact(val).empty?" should be "when Hash   then val.compact.empty?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove nil

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
=> {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>nil}
hash.inject({}){|c, (k, v)| c[k] = v unless v.nil?; c}
=> {:a=>true, :b=>false}
```

Comment: or simply `hash.compact!`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I have:

```
# recursively remove empty keys (hashes), values (array), hashes and arrays from hash or array
def sanitize data
  case data
  when Array
    data.delete_if { |value| res = sanitize(value); res.blank? }
  when Hash
    data.delete_if { |_, value| res = sanitize(value); res.blank? }
  end
  data.blank? ? nil : data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep deletion nil values from a hash.

```
  # returns new instance of hash with deleted nil values
  def self.deep_remove_nil_values(hash)
    hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), new_hash|
      new_hash[k] = deep_remove_nil_values(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash[k] = v unless v.nil?
    end
  end

  # rewrite current hash
  def self.deep_remove_nil_values!(hash)
    hash.each do |k, v|
      deep_remove_nil_values(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)
      hash.delete(k) if v.nil?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

in ruby 2.7 there are standard `compact` and `transform_values` methods, on the Hash so you can do this like this:

```
class Hash 
  def deep_compact
    compact.transform_values{|vl| vl.is_a?(Hash) ? vl.deep_compact : vl }
  end
end
```

It's the neatiest implementation, imho.

Answer (score -1):

```
  validated_params
    .to_h
    .delete_if {|_,v| !v.present? }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, consider adding an explanation of how this code fixes the problem. And because this is such an old question with many other answers, you should explain what your solution adds/addresses that the others do not.