# How to recursively remove all keys with empty values from (YAML) hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, yaml

I have been trying to get rid of all hash keys in my YAML file that have empty (blank) values or empty hashes as values.

This [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450641/ruby-removing-all-empty-elements-from-a-hash-yaml) helped me to get it almost right, but the recursive one-liner leaves my YAML dump with empty hashes whenever there is sufficiently deep nesting.

I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

```
proc = Proc.new { |k, v| (v.kind_of?(Hash) && !v.empty? ) ? (v.delete_if(&proc); nil) : v.blank? }

hash = {"x"=>{"m"=>{"n"=>{}}}, 'y' => 'content'}
hash.delete_if(&proc)
```

Actual output

```
 {"x"=>{"m"=>{}}, "y"=>"content"}
```

Desired output

```
{"y"=>"content"}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.empty? or v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty?}
  end
end

p hash.delete_blank
# => {"y"=>"content"}
```

Comment: My version (rails):

class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.blank? or (v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty?)}
  end
end

Comment: User blank? instead of empty? because it will fail at nil

Comment: Any reason why you use delete_if instead of reject?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more generic method:

```
class Hash
  def deep_reject(&blk)
    self.dup.deep_reject!(&blk)
  end

  def deep_reject!(&blk)
    self.each do |k, v|
      v.deep_reject!(&blk)  if v.is_a?(Hash)
      self.delete(k)  if blk.call(k, v)
    end
  end
end

{ a: 1, b: nil, c: { d: nil, e: '' } }.deep_reject! { |k, v| v.blank? }
==> { a: 1 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this the most correct version:

```
h = {a: {b: {c: "",}, d:1}, e:2, f: {g: {h:''}}}
p = proc do |_, v|
  v.delete_if(&p) if v.respond_to? :delete_if
  v.nil? || v.respond_to?(:"empty?") && v.empty?
end
h.delete_if(&p)
#=> {:a=>{:d=>1}, :e=>2}
```

Comment: @DavidWest
`p` is a recursive `proc`;
if the value `v` is a map-like object (responds to `delete_if`), then we prune all the empty value in it;
if `v` is empty (or a `nil` value) then we remove it (return `true` to `delete_if`). 
Is this explanation enough? :)

Comment: Very elegant. I am impressed. I am not familiar with the ampersand. Why is that used? I am going to look into procs more after reading this. Is there a keyword that i can use to learn more about the ampersand? Is it like the one that one uses with &block?

Comment: Yes, it's nearly the same thing. When used in the definition of a method, `&block` capture any block passed to the method and transform it into a proc. When used before an argument, it goes the other way: transform a proc into a block. To be honest, this aren't cheap instruction and should be avoided if possible xD But yes, they allow some nice trick ^^

Comment: What would be a way to accomplish the same thing if our hash also included values that were arrays of hashes?

For example `h = {a: {b: {c: "",}, d:1}, e:2, f: {g: {h:''}}, j: [ {k: 1, l: nil } ]}`

Comment: Nothing change, because arrays also have `#delete_if`. This is the power of duck-typing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old but I came up with a better solution which supports Multidimensional hashes. It uses delete_if? except its multidimensional and cleans out anything with a an empty value by default and if a block is passed it is passed down through it's children.

```
# Hash cleaner
class Hash
    def clean!
        self.delete_if do |key, val|
            if block_given?
                yield(key,val)
            else
                # Prepeare the tests
                test1 = val.nil?
                test2 = val === 0
                test3 = val === false
                test4 = val.empty? if val.respond_to?('empty?')
                test5 = val.strip.empty? if val.is_a?(String) && val.respond_to?('empty?')

                # Were any of the tests true
                test1 || test2 || test3 || test4 || test5
            end
        end

        self.each do |key, val|
            if self[key].is_a?(Hash) && self[key].respond_to?('clean!')
                if block_given?
                    self[key] = self[key].clean!(&Proc.new)
                else
                    self[key] = self[key].clean!
                end
            end
        end

        return self
    end
end
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12360142/419

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"x"=>{"m"=>{"n"=>{}}}, 'y' => 'content'}
clean = proc{ |k,v| !v.empty? ? Hash === v ? v.delete_if(&clean) : false : true }
hash.delete_if(&clean)
#=> {"y"=>"content"}
```

or like @sawa suggested, you can use this proc

```
clean = proc{ |k,v| v.empty? or Hash === v && v.delete_if(&clean) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit related thing. If you want to delete specified keys from nested hash:

```
def find_and_destroy(*keys)
    delete_if{ |k, v| (keys.include?(k.to_s) ? true : ( (v.each { |vv| vv = vv.find_and_destroy(*keys) }) if v.instance_of?(Array) ;  (v.each { |vv| vv = vv.find_and_destroy(*keys) }) if v.instance_of?(Hash); false) )}
end
```

.You can also customize it further