# Recursive method not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975498/how-to-recursively-remove-all-keys-with-empty-values-from-yaml-hash) on Hash that deletes key-value pairs whose value is blank. It does that recursively for nested hashes as well.

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if { |k, v| v.empty? || v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty? }
  end
end
```

Running it from console works:

```
{
  "customer_id"=>"foo",
  "document_id"=>"",
  "status"=>"",
  "total"=>{"from"=>"1", "to"=>""}
}.delete_blank
#=> {"customer_id"=>"foo", "total"=>{"from"=>"1"}}

{
  "customer_id"=>"",
  "document_id"=>"",
  "status"=>"",
  "total"=>{"from"=>"", "to"=>""}
}.delete_blank
#=> {}
```

I put the code above in my Rails project in `lib/core_ext/hash.rb`, then required the file. I am trying to use it in a model concern. However, it does not remove blank pairs in nested hashes:

```
{
  "customer_id"=>"",
  "document_id"=>"",
  "status"=>"",
  "total"=>{"from"=>"", "to"=>""}
}.delete_blank
#=> {"total"=>{"from"=>"", "to"=>""}}
```

Why does the recursive part of the method not work as expected in the app (while it works in `rails c`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases Rails uses `HashWithIndifferentAccess` class so I suppose your check `v.instance_of?(Hash)` can be false.

#### Workaround:

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if { |k, v| v.empty? || v.kind_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty? }
  end
end
```

Comment: but won't that also make it fail in `rails console` ?

Comment: In the console you used a normal Hash. You can try with something like
`h = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new`

Comment: You can use `v.kind_of(Hash)` and it will correctly detect `Hash` and `HashWithIndifferentAccess` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F