# Rails - Calling a Method on Action Controller Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement the **method** found in the **below discussion** to delete from my my **strong params** all fields that are blank.

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.empty? or v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty?}
  end
end

p hash.delete_blank
# => {"y"=>"content"}
```

[How to recursively remove all keys with empty values from (YAML) hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975498/how-to-recursively-remove-all-keys-with-empty-values-from-yaml-hash)

This are location_params from which I want to remove the empty fields:

```
def location_params
params.require(:location).permit(:country, {:ads_attributes => [:remote]})
end
```

The following error triggers when I call the following **delete_blank** method on **location_params**

```
undefined method "delete_blank" for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007.....>
```

My opinion is that I have to modify the *Hash Class* in my *Rails project*, but I do not know how to do it and I think it may not be the best solution.

Thanks a lot for your help
Fabrizio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure returned by Rails `params` method looks like a Hash, but actually it is an instance of [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Since `delete_blank` is not defined on `ActionController::Parameters`, but on `Hash` you get this error: `undefined method "delete_blank" for #<ActionController::Parameters...`

You have two options:

A) Define the method on `ActionController::Parameters`:

```
class ActionController::Parameters
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.empty? or v.instance_of?(Hash) && v.delete_blank.empty?}
  end
end
```

Or B) translate the instance of `ActionController::Parameters` into a `Hash`, call the method and translate it back:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(params.to_h.delete_blank).permit!
```

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot!