# remove the key and value in the params hash with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

hello how is to remove empty value or nil in ruby on rails 
I try to reject the method but it does not work there are there any other method?

Here is my hash with empty values

```
 {
 first_name: {
         1: "david",
         2: ""
       },
  last_name: {
        1: "david",
        2: ""
       },
  role: {
     1: "dev",
     2: ""
   },
  bio: {
    1: "commercial",
    2: ""
  },
```

thank you

Comment: this isn't a valid hash also you didn't list what you expect the output to be.  Should `first_name` just have 'david' or since it's blank that key & value gets removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Hash
  def compact(opts={})
    inject({}) do |new_hash, (k,v)|
      if !v.blank?
        new_hash[k] = opts[:recursive] && v.class == Hash ? v.compact(opts) : v
      end
      new_hash
    end
  end
end

hash = {
    :first_name=> {
        1=> "david",
    2=> ""
},
    :last_name=> {
    1=> "david",
    2=> ""
},
    :role=> {
    1=> "dev",
    2=> ""
},
    :bio=> {
    1=> "commercial",
    2=> ""
}
}


hash.compact(:recursive=>true)
```

will give

```
{
  :first_name => {
    1 => "david"
  },
   :last_name => {
    1 => "david"
  },
        :role => {
    1 => "dev"
  },
         :bio => {
    1 => "commercial"
  }
}
```

source: [Removing all empty elements from a hash / YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450641/ruby-removing-all-empty-elements-from-a-hash-yaml)

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.each {|_, v| v.delete_if {|_, v| v == ""}}

#=> {"first_name"=>{1=>"david"}, "last_name"=>{1=>"david"}, "role"=>{1=>"dev"}, "bio"=>{1=>"commercial"}}
```