# Deleting NilClass values from hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to remove values of `NilClass` from a hash:

```
args = { 'name' => 'myname', 'description' => NilClass, 'homepage' => NilClass,
         'private' => NilClass, 'has_issues' => NilClass, 'has_wiki' => false,
         'has_downloads' => NilClass }
```

I tried the following:

```
args.reject!{|k,v| v.nil?}
```

This returns the original hash with all values still present.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Let's start with finding out how those are getting there. You're parsing something and values are missing and the hash ends up with nils? If so, it's better to deal with the first problem so you don't have nils, than it is to generate a bunch of nil values and then have to clean them up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea, however the value of `NilClass` in Ruby is not nil. Try it out yourself?

```
NilClass.nil?
=> false
```

You have to specifically reject values equal to `NilClass`.

```
args.reject! { |key, value| value == NilClass }
```

Comment: You can use `_` for the key argument, since you really don't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a monkeypatching and add a compact method to your hash class as described on this post.

[Removing all empty elements from a hash / YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450641/removing-all-empty-elements-from-a-hash-yaml)