# How do I remove specific 'nil' values from a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following hash:

```
H = {"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil, "d" => nil}
```

I want to preserve the `nil` value with `"c"`, and remove the `nil` value with `"d"`. How can I do that?

Applying `compact` will remove all `nil` values (i.e., with keys `"c"` and `"d"`).

Question [Removing all empty elements from a hash / YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450641/removing-all-empty-elements-from-a-hash-yaml) addresses this issue, but I thought there could have been a function equivalent to `.compact`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all empty elements from a hash / YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450641/removing-all-empty-elements-from-a-hash-yaml)

Comment: Even though @tadman has provided a pretty nice solution, please consider adding your attempts to solve your problem whenever asking a question.

Comment: @coderade That's not a duplicate.

Comment: @RutvikOnline Your question is `ruby` only. You can remove `ruby-on-rails` tag.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"I want to preserve one of them"*? Do you mean "the first one"? Or "a specific one"? Or something else?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh There is no reason to assume this is "ruby only". If this is for a Rails app, there are thousands of Rails-specific extensions to Ruby that may be relevant. The answer to many Ruby-only questions might be quite long, but if the `ruby-on-rails` tag is included, the answers may be single line method invocations because of some extension Rails provides.

Comment: _"The answer to many Ruby-only questions might be quite long"_ - @meagar i agree to this. But for this particular question, it can be solved in one line with ruby only. At least with the current question description, it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) for that:

```
h.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
```

Where `k,v` represents the key/value pair.

If you can quantify why you want the `c` key preserved you can incorporate that in the logic. Is it just the first `nil` that's saved?

If that's the case, you can try this:

```
count = 0
h.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? && (count += 1) != 1 }
```

Note that Ruby is a case sensitive language and `H` is a constant by virtue of being a capital letter. For variables use lower-case only.

Additionally, the traditional way to declare a Ruby hash is:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil, "d" => nil }
```

Where that's only if you want string keys. With Symbol keys it's even more concise:

```
h = { a: 100, b: 200, c: nil, d: nil }
```

Comment: He says he wants to preserve one of them, yours would delete every value which has the nil value.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Added clarification for that.

Comment: Something like `h.delete_if{|k,v| k != "c" && v.nil?}`, perhaps?

Comment: `Hash#delete_if` is the same as `Hash#reject!`. Depending on requirements, `Hash#reject`, which does not mutate the hash, may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil, "d" => nil]
```

If the resulting key order is not important you could write:

```
h.compact.merge("c" => nil)
  #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>nil}
```

or

```
h.compact!.update("c" => nil)
```

if the hash is to be modified in place.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one key, why not [Hash#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-delete) to remove the pair from the Hash instance?

```
h = {"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil, "d" => nil}
h.delete("d") 
h # => {"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point, once you know that a specific key must be `nil`, for example `"c"` you could do something like:

```
h = {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>nil, "d"=>nil}
h.compact!["c"] = nil

# => {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>nil}
```

Now, if you call `h["c"]` you get `nil`.

Consider also that when you simply do `h.compact!` and call `h["c"]` you get `nil` anyway.

Comment: This gives `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass)` with `{"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}` as `compact!` returns `nil` if there is no change in original hash.

Comment: Good point @JagdeepSingh! I meant, if you already know that some values are `nil` and want to preserve one of those key. This is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Yes, `h["c"]` will return `nil`, but so will `h["d"]` and any other key not in the hash, which is why one needs to use `h.key?("c")` when values can be `nil` (a good practice generally).